# Why HDF5 make InpInput/output error and how to solve it

Tags: c++, cluster-computing, hdf5

I am using a C++ code to do some scientific calculation and this code uses the HDF5 library to save data. Sometimes, after a long-running time, HDF5 makes error as following:

```
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to flush data from cache
  #006: H5Dint.c line 2940 in H5D__flush_sieve_buf(): block write failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
  #007: H5Fio.c line 195 in H5F_block_write(): write through page buffer failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
  #008: H5PB.c line 1041 in H5PB_write(): write through metadata accumulator failed
    major: Page Buffering
    minor: Write failed
  #009: H5Faccum.c line 834 in H5F__accum_write(): file write failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
  #010: H5FDint.c line 308 in H5FD_write(): driver write request failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Write failed
  #011: H5FDsec2.c line 810 in H5FD_sec2_write(): file write failed: time = Fri Jan 24 13:09:19 2020
, filename = 'result.hdf5', file descriptor = 3, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 0x6651868, total write size = 16200, bytes this sub-write = 16200, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 412577956
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.1) thread 0:
  #000: H5D.c line 339 in H5Dclose(): can't decrement count on dataset ID
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to decrement reference count
  #001: H5I.c line 1410 in H5I_dec_app_ref_always_close(): can't decrement ID ref count
    major: Object atom
    minor: Unable to decrement reference count
  #002: H5I.c line 1352 in H5I_dec_app_ref(): can't decrement ID ref count
    major: Object atom
    minor: Unable to decrement reference count
  #003: H5Dint.c line 1802 in H5D_close(): unable to flush cached dataset info
    major: Dataset
    minor: Write failed
  #004: H5Dint.c line 2980 in H5D__flush_real(): unable to flush raw data
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to flush data from cache
  #005: H5Dcontig.c line 1315 in H5D__contig_flush(): unable to flush sieve buffer
    major: Dataset
    minor: Unable to flush data from cache
  #006: H5Dint.c line 2940 in H5D__flush_sieve_buf(): block write failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
  #007: H5Fio.c line 195 in H5F_block_write(): write through page buffer failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
  #008: H5PB.c line 1041 in H5PB_write(): write through metadata accumulator failed
    major: Page Buffering
    minor: Write failed
  #009: H5Faccum.c line 834 in H5F__accum_write(): file write failed
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
  #010: H5FDint.c line 308 in H5FD_write(): driver write request failed
    major: Virtual File Layer
    minor: Write failed
  #011: H5FDsec2.c line 810 in H5FD_sec2_write(): file write failed: time = Fri Jan 24 13:10:16 2020
, filename = 'result.hdf5', file descriptor = 3, errno = 5, error message = 'Input/output error', buf = 0x6651868, total write size = 16200, bytes this sub-write = 16200, bytes actually written = 18446744073709551615, offset = 412596204
    major: Low-level I/O
    minor: Write failed
```

Could you please help me to solve this problem?

OS : Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

HDF5 Version : 1.10.1

Comment: *Sometimes, after a long-running time ...* I suspect that you may have run out of scratch space.  I'm guessing, perhaps wildly, that your computation uses scratch space and you only transfer results to more permanent storage after the computation completes.

Comment: yes. it does. do you mean changing the scratch space directory solves this problem?

Comment: I don't know, but the symptoms you report suggested to me that your computation ran out of space to write results to.  My next step would be to either increase the space available or to reduce the volume of data written, to see if my guess was in the right ball park.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but I did not understand what I should do! I should increase the available space of directory which result is written in or increase/ change the scratch space?

Comment: Actually I save the result in my home directory but the C++ code, which I am using, creates an HDF5 file and after completion of calculation (usually, it takes a long time) close it. During calculation,  data is added to the HDF5 file.

Comment: I also had some weird problems with the C++ API. I therefore switch to [HighFive](https://github.com/BlueBrain/HighFive) that providing a C++ API but use HDF5's C functions. Since the switch I never had issues.